# Searching for pieces of an attribute with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to use Beautiful Soup to pull out anything with the following format:

```
div class="dog-a b-cat"
```

I can get a particular instance if I know what "a" and "b" are by doing the following (suppose `a=aardvark` and `b=boy`):

```
soup.find_all("div",class_="dog-aardvark boy-cat")
```

Is there any way I can pull out all instances (regardless of the two words between the dashes) with dog and cat and two dashes in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bourbaki4481472 is on the right track in general but the proposed solution would not work because of multiple reasons, starting with that the specified *regular expression would be matched against a single class at a time*, since `class` is a special [multi-valued attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) and ending with it's simply *syntactically incorrect*.

I suggest you make a [filtering function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) that would check that the first class value starts-with `dog-` and the second one ends with `-cat`. You may improve it by additionally checking the tag name or how much class values are present if needed:

```
def class_filter(elm):
    try:
        classes = elm["class"]
        return classes[0].startswith("dog-") and classes[1].endswith("-cat")
    except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
        return False
```

Complete example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="dog-test test-cat">test1</div>
<div class="dog-test">test2</div>
<div class="test-cat">test3</div>
<div class="dog">test4</div>
<div class="cat">test5</div>
<div class="irrelevant">test6</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

def class_filter(elm):
    try:
        classes = elm["class"]
        return classes[0].startswith("dog-") and classes[1].endswith("-cat")
    except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
        return False

for elm in soup.find_all(class_filter):
    print(elm.text)
```

Prints `test1` only.

Comment: Both your answer and your explanation of why simpler answers won't work have helped me better understand what I'm doing as well as solve the problem at hand. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) to generalize your parameters.

```
import re
soup.find_all("div", class= re.compile(r"dog-.+ boy-.+")
```

The above would look for strings `dog-` followed by one or more characters, followed by [space], and followed by `boy-` followed by one or more characters.

Comment: Please see my answer explaining why this solution would not work. Thanks.